# Python Pandas : Extend operation of a column if a condition matches

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two different dataframes, i.e.,

```
firstDF = pd.DataFrame([{'mac':1,'location':['kitchen']}])
predictedDF = pd.DataFrame([{'mac':1,'location':['lab']}])
```

If the mac column value of predictedDF contains in mac column value of firstDF , then location column value of firstDF should extend the location column of predictedDF and the result of firstDF should be,

```
firstDF
      mac    location
0     1      ['kitchen','lab']
```

I have tried with,

```
firstDF.loc[firstDF['mac'] == predictedDF['mac'], 'mac'] = firstDF.loc[firstDF['location'].extend(predictedDF['location']), 'location']
```

Whereas the same returns,

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

Comment: I add test with more values, output is like you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If lists in `location` columns first [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for one `DataFrame` and then join with `+` and [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column (use and drop):

```
df = firstDF.merge(predictedDF, on='mac', how='left')
df['location'] = df.pop('location_x') + df.pop('location_y')
print (df)
   mac        location
0    1  [kitchen, lab]
```

Test with more values - if missing values then replace them to `[]`:

```
firstDF = pd.DataFrame({'mac':[1, 2],'location':[['kitchen'],['kitchen']]})
predictedDF = pd.DataFrame([{'mac':1,'location':['lab']}])

df = firstDF.merge(predictedDF, on='mac', how='left').applymap(lambda x: x if x == x else [])
df['location'] = df.pop('location_x') + df.pop('location_y')
print (df)
   mac        location
0    1  [kitchen, lab]
1    2       [kitchen]
```

Comment: Thank you, Its indeed a case to be taken care. How about retaining the location column value for mac=2 in df?

Comment: @MahamuthaM - Then is possible replace missing values by `[]` with applymap. Answer was edited.